# Partial credentials found in env, missing: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY on github action

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-s3, github-actions

I've tried everything to fix this issue with my GitHub action, but I keep getting the error message "Partial credentials found in shared-credentials-file, missing: aws_secret_access_key." I would like to understand how to resolve this issue, considering that my credentials are correctly configured.

Please find below my code for evaluation:

````
```
`name: Deploy to Dev and Prod Environments
yaml
````

> > ```
> > on:
> > push:
> > branches:
> > - main
> > ```
>
> ````
> jobs:
> deploy:
> runs-on: ubuntu-latest
> steps:
> - uses: actions/checkout@master
> - uses: jakejarvis/s3-sync-action@master
> with:
> args: --acl public-read --follow-symlinks --delete --exclude '.git*/*'
> env:
> AWS_S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.AWS_S3_BUCKET}}
> AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
> AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
> AWS_REGION: us-east-2`
> ```
> ````

````
I would appreciate any help to understand and fix this issue.

`your text`


I've tried everything to fix this issue with my GitHub action, but I keep getting the error message "Partial credentials found in shared-credentials-file, missing: aws_secret_access_key." I would like to understand how to resolve this issue, considering that my credentials are correctly configured.

Please find below my code for evaluation:

```
name: Deploy to Dev and Prod Environments

on:
push:
branches:
- main

jobs:
deploy:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@master
- uses: jakejarvis/s3-sync-action@master
with:
args: --acl public-read --follow-symlinks --delete --exclude '.git*/*'
env:
AWS_S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.AWS_S3_BUCKET}}
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
AWS_REGION: us-east-2
```
````

I would appreciate any help to understand and fix this issue.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76203487/edit) your question and format those workflows. As of now, both are invalid due to formatting issues. You may use https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ to fix those issues. Verify if those secrets are properly configured.